# Get different checking results from CRAN feedback

Tags: r, build, package, cran

I am trying to publish my R package. I ran 'check' from R studio and got a clean OK (without Notes or Errors). 
After submitting it, I got feedback from CRAN saying that I have NOTES about "no visible global function definition for ‘quantile’"

I re-checked my package on R studio and got a clean OK again. I didn't see this note on my end. Does anyone know why we get different checking results?

Comment: I've run into this too. What I've deduced from it is that there has been a change in how they check and you now need to import *any* function from the `stats` library into your package. I also have not been able to replicate the same notes on my machine. Perhaps using the very latest version of R would reveal this?

Comment: You're likely not running `R CMD check --as-cran`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: my experience as been that `R CMD check --as-cran` does *not* catch this. Neither did winbuilder. But let me check if it's an issue of not updating to 3.2.3 yet...

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: I just edited by NAMESPACE to `#importFrom("graphics", "legend", "lines", "par", "plot")` and ran `R CMD check icenReg --as-cran` (v3.2.3) and got no notes about this. Also, I can confirm that this started to arise well after v3.0.0; I had a package on CRAN that passed early this year that used `plot`, etc., with no complaints. Then around August (not accurate), I got a note from CRAN that I needed to import `plot`, etc.

Comment: Perhaps it was more closely monitored after August and that's why it wasn't until then that CRAN informed me of this? But I still cannot replicate those NOTEs on my machine.

Comment: @CliffAB: CRAN runs `R CMD check` using R-devel, and [this behavior has been in effect since late June this year](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2015/06/29#n2015-06-29).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Ah, that explains it perfectly. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Yeah it makes sense. Since I cannot replicate those NOTEs so I don't know if I have fixed it or not.

Comment: I believe you should be able to replicate it using http://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx and using R-devel, yes?

Comment: @CliffAB Yes, that link is really helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the best place to catch these things today (if your problem is not OS specific) is with [win-builder](http://win-builder.r-project.org/upload.aspx) as some people have said in the comments.

The `devtools` package has a really convenient function to send your package to `win-builder`, just run `build_win()` when inside your `Rstudio` project for the package. It will compile the package and then upload it to win-builder, which will run tests both on the `R-release` and `R-devel` and thensend you the link for the results on the email specified on the description file.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am using R studio and devtools so this is very convenient for me to use. It works like a magic!

Comment: @Yukun you should also take a look at the `release()` function, it is really useful.

Comment: I have just checked it out! This is an awesome function as well. Where did you find all those useful functions?

Comment: Great book! Thanks for sharing it with me. I can't wait to read it. Also, Hadley is a great author.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been part of R-devel since late June this year (see [here](http://developer.r-project.org/blosxom.cgi/R-devel/NEWS/2015/06/29#n2015-06-29) for details). As it says in the [CRAN Repository Policy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/policies.html):

> Please ensure that R CMD check --as-cran has been run on the tarball to be uploaded before submission. This should be done with the current version of R-devel (or if that is not possible and explained in the submission, current R-patched or the current release of R.)

So, you need to run `R CMD check --as-cran` on your package, using R-devel.

Comment: I have seen this in the policy. Just confused that how to use this command? Like `check packagename--as-cran`? Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: @Yukun: You run `R CMD check yourpackage.tar.gz --as-cran` from the command line. There may be a way to do that with RStudio, but I don't know.